# while creating sandbox tester Email shouild be dummy or real?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, app-store-connect

I'm going to test In App Purchase in my app ...
Filling of sandbox tester form , within it emailid and password , we have to enter real email Id or dummy should work...?

Comment: dummy will work

Comment: and can I test that in simulator ?

Comment: no you can't  test iap in simulator.

Comment: what about app shared secret ? how it affects on app , it is compulsory to add in IAP ?